# Get an internal site to work with Azure App Proxy

Tags: .net, azure

We are looking at using Azure App Proxy to allow user access to some of our internal sites. I have setup the Application Proxy and can access the site.
The issue I`m having is all of the links to CSS , JQuery and other scripts get a 404 error even though if I access the site internally all is good. It seems App Proxy is not seeing them. Do I need to replace all the links with App Proxy links or am I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

**When you publish an Application Proxy app, only pages under your root are accessible when accessing the application.** If the page isn’t displaying correctly, the root internal URL used for the application may be missing some page resources. To resolve, make sure you have published all the resources for the page as part of your application.

**404 errors indicate that indicates the pages currently cannot be found and that you need to publish them.**

As an example of this case, assume you have published an expenses application using the internal URL `http://myapps/expenses`, but the app uses the stylesheet `http://myapps/style.css`. In this case, the stylesheet is not published in your application, so loading the expenses app throw a 404 error while trying to load `style.css`. **In this example, the problem is resolved by publishing the application with an internal URL `http://myapp/`.**

To know more details about this, refer [Application page does not display correctly for an Application Proxy application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-page-appearance-broken-problem).

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had was I using a URL http://site/controller/action and because of this the Application Proxy could not see the links / folders for the root of the site at http://site/ , changing the URL to the root solved the issue.